# VSCode build task opens shell and stops without running command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am currently attempting to run a build.bat script that builds my solution with the VSCode build tasks. Unfortunately all it does is open the command prompt without running the actual command as instructed. The task I'm currently attempting to run is

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "W:\\handmade\\code",
                    "shell": {
                        "args": [
                            "/k W:\\handmade\\misc\\shell.bat"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "command": "build.bat",
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'd expect as output is:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.8.4
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

W:\handmade\code>build.bat
A subdirectory or file ..\..\build already exists.
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.15.26729 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

win32_handmade.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.15.26729.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:win32_handmade.exe
/debug
win32_handmade.obj
user32.lib
```

Which is what I get if I run the command normally, what I get instead is

```
> Executing task: build.bat <

**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.8.4
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

W:\handmade\code>
```

And then it hangs until exit is called. The command provided in the tasks.json is clearly never attempted executed and I'm at my wit's end as to why this is.

Comment: Have you changed the internal vscode terminal?